# One-liner for updating a value in a list of dictionaries - Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
l = [{"integer":"1"},{"integer":"2"},{"integer":"3"},{"integer":"4"}]
```

I would like to do something similar to the following so that each of the numbers which are the value pair for the "integer" key are returned as integers:

```
l = [{"integer":"1"},{"integer":"2"},{"integer":"3"},{"integer":"4"}]
r = map(lambda x: x["integer"]=int(x["integer"]), l)
print r 
#[{"integer":1},{"integer":2},{"integer":3},{"integer":4}]
```

But this causes an error:

> `SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment`

Does anyone know of a clean way to do this in python? Preferably a oneliner using map or something similar?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Do you have other keys which correspond to values that are not integers?

Comment: @pault - My apologies, I should have mentioned, lambdas don't like assignment, so this code doesn't run.

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? It's a simple for loop.

Comment: You could always define a function to encapsulate it.

Comment: @Barmar one-liners make you smarter obviously haha jk but I myself think there is a certain appeal to one liners, don't you think?

Comment: If you're entering code golf competitions. For production code, less so.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension comprehension

You will iterate through the dictionaries in the list and have them returned as `x`, then insert a new dictionary with your desired key and the integer value of the return within a new list

```
r = [{'integer': int(x['integer'])} for x in l]
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to do that without having to redefine the whole dictionary?

Comment: @JustinGardner Still just in 1 line?

Answer (score 3):

You should just use a loop:

```
l = [{"integer":"1"},{"integer":"2"},{"integer":"3"},{"integer":"4"}]
for d in l:
    d["integer"] = int(d["integer"])
print(l)
#[{'integer': 1}, {'integer': 2}, {'integer': 3}, {'integer': 4}]
```

However, here is a one-liner that should work for you:

```
l = [{"integer":"1"},{"integer":"2"},{"integer":"3"},{"integer":"4"}]
[d.update({"integer": int(d["integer"])}) for d in l]
print(l)
#[{'integer': 1}, {'integer': 2}, {'integer': 3}, {'integer': 4}]
```

Be aware that `dict.update()` returns `None`, so if you assigned the output of the list comprehension to a variable it would be a list containing all `None`s.

```
print([d.update({"integer": int(d["integer"])}) for d in l])
#[None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works in one line:

```
r = [{'integer':int(x['integer'])} for x in l]
print(r)
# [{'integer': 1}, {'integer': 2}, {'integer': 3}, {'integer': 4}]
```

This utilizes a dict comprehension inside a list comprehension.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do that without having to redefine the whole dictionary?

Comment: You could just say `l = [{'integer':int(x['integer'])} for x in l]` followed by `print(l)`. I just followed your code where you defined a new variable `r`, but you don't necessarily need to do this.

Comment: @Joel His code assigns a new variable, but it also modifies the original dictionaries in place (or would, if it were legal). It seems that the in-place modification is what he's really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
[i.update({w:int(k)}) for i in l for w,k in i.items()]
```

it the second loop is only looping over one key set, so take the two loops with gram of salt :)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome solution by one of my friends in a chat:

```
>>> listOfDict = [{1:1338}, {1:1338}, {1:1338}]
>>> y = 1337
>>> value = 1
>>> map(lambda x: x.update({value: y}), listOfDict)
[None, None, None]
>>> listOfDict
[{1: 1337}, {1: 1337}, {1: 1337}]
```

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52282310/5858851), except you replaced the list comp with a call to `map`. BTW, this won't work in python3. In any case, I still say that you should just use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
l = [{"integer":"1"},{"integer":"2"},{"integer":"3"},{"integer":"4"}]
a = [dict(d, **{'abcd':5}) for d in l]
print(a)
[{'integer': '1', 'abcd': 4}, {'integer': '2', 'abcd': 4}, {'integer': '3', 'abcd': 4}, {'integer': '4', 'abcd': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/2893024) to copy keyword arguments from the existing dicts, then overwrite the ones you want like so:

```
[{**element, 'value_to_overwrite':'new value'} for element in list_of_dicts]
```